# Find the order of $\sigma^{1000}$ where $\sigma$ is the permutation (1,3,8)(2,7)(4,9,6,5)

Tags: group-theory, permutations

My book doesn't have any examples of how to do this, so I'm a little lost. I know the order of a permutation is the lowest common multiple of the lengths of its disjoint factors, and so the order of $\sigma$ is lcm(3, 2, 4) = 12. My thinking was that since $\sigma^{1000}$ = $\sigma^{12*83}$$\sigma^{4}$ = $\sigma^{4}$ = (1,3,8)$^{4}$(2,7)$^{4}$(4,9,6,5)$^{4}$, I could simply take lcm(3$^{4}$, 2$^{4}$, 4$^{4}$) = 12$^{4}$ = 20, 736 for the order of $\sigma^{4}$. But I honestly just pulled that from nowhere, not once does my book discuss anything related to modular arithmetic and so I really don't know if this is correct. Am I on the right path or am I completely incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of a cycle is its length, and the order of a product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of their orders, i.e.  the l.c.m. of their lengths. Hence $\sigma$ has order $12$, so that $\sigma^{1000}=\sigma^{1000\bmod 12}=\sigma^4$. So $\sigma^{1000}\,$ has order $\dfrac{12}{4}=3$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. There wasn't anything like this is my book, but I should have been able to see this. I'll accept your answer as the solution when it lets me in two minutes. Thank you again.

Comment: @ben: it is only a rough sketch, the details may depend on the results you're supposed to know.The assertion concerning the order of a product  of disjoint cycles is  a matter of common sense. The assertion on the order of a power of an element (it's $\dfrac{\mathrm {order\ of\ element}}{\gcd(\mathrm{power},\mathrm {order\ of\ element})}$), it is to be found in chapters on cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2):

Because $2 \mid 1000$ and $4 \mid 1000$ ,  those cycles are resolved back to identity in $\sigma^{1000}$. So you are left with the 3-cycle (at first position, $1000 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$) and $\sigma^{1000}=(1,3,8)$.